# In ASP.NET/C#, how do I get data from the database into a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, webforms

I have a class in ASP.NET to retrieve stylesheet related data from a database.

> *Disclaimer:* I understand it's not optimal to do it like this, but this is how my teacher wants it.

I need to make a website that everything (text, background-image, etc.) with the exception of tags comes directly from the database. My problem is: I'm not able to take my data and insert it directly into my CSS stylesheet.

I'm turning around something like this:

#### C# Code

```cs
SqlCommand body_bg = new SqlCommand("Select * from image_back where placement='body';", conn);
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = body_bg.ExecuteReader();

while (reader) 
    bod_back = reader["nom"].ToString();
```

#### HTML markup

```html
<body runat="server" style="background-image:url(<%bod_back%>);">
```

> *Note:* It would be better if this were directly in the CSS stylesheet. I already tried that, however, without success.

#### Database columns

- `placement` = *BODY* (where I put the image; e.g., in this case for the body background)
- `nom` = */images/bodyback.jpg*

Is there any ways to make that happen?

Comment: I don't understand why the first sentence is in the question when the mentioned class isn't.  Relevance?  What class are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's actually no reason you couldn't dynamically generate a CSS file using ASP.NET. Unless you're relying on some of the more opinionated server controls, ASP.NET doesn't really care if you're outputting HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or even binary files such as PNGs. So, assuming this is ASP.NET Web Forms (which it appears to be) you might have a call to e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css.aspx">`. In fact, to satisfy fussy browsers, you could even set the MIME type in that `.aspx` type with e.g. `Response.ContentType = "text/css"`.

Comment: That said, if your styles are specific to each page, and/or are changing per request, then it probably makes more sense to embed your styles via the `<style />` element. Alternatively, if your styles _are_ shared across the site—or, at least, multiple pages—then you'll likely want to apply some level of output caching to your e.g. `styles.css.aspx` page so that it doesn't need to pull the data from the database each and every request. I'm assuming, of course, that your CSS isn't changing frequently.

Comment: Also, Sebastien, what isn't working with your current approach? What problem are you running into? Is there an error message? Is nothing being returned? Is the wrong data being output?

Comment: Fact is that you can inject your css files in your markup from code behind and you can write stylesheet files as well and you can just put stylesheets in your markup with your code behind. You have the power. I would recommend you to see `asp.net Literal` controls to check how they render and how you can inject your styles in it.

Comment: There is a typo in your markup, should probably be: `<body runat="server" style="background-image:url(<%=bod_back%>);">`

Comment: It still doesnt work but thanks a lot, really appreciate !

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I'm assuming you are using the ASP.NET Web Forms framework. As mentioned in the comments, there's no reason you can't create an `.aspx` file to output a CSS stylesheet. While Web Forms defaults to outputting HTML (i.e., `text/html`), it can be used to output JavaScript, JSON, or even binary files such as PNGs.

Obviously, to create a CSS stylesheet, you won't want to use any opinionated server controls that output HTML. And, to be safe, you should set the `ContentType` to `text/css` so that picky browsers don't complain about the MIME type mismatch. But, outside of that, this should look just like a normal Web Forms page.

Given this, your code might look something like the following:

> *Disclaimer:* This is going to be pseudocode, as I don't have an environment ready to test this in and it's been years since I've written ASP.NET Web Forms code.

#### `styles.css.aspx.cs`

```cs
Response.ContentType = "text/css";

var backgroundRecords = new SqlCommand("select * from image_back;", conn);
var backgroundImages = new Dictionary<string, string>();

conn.Open();

var reader = backgroundRecords.ExecuteReader();

while (reader) {
  backgroundImages.Add(
    reader["placement"].ToString(), 
    reader["nom"].ToString()
  );
}

BackgroundStyles.DataSource = backgroundImages;
BackgroundStyles.DataBind();
```

#### `styles.css.aspx`

```
<asp:Repeater id="BackgroundStyles" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("Key") %> {
      background-image: url('<%# Eval("Value") %>');
    }
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

#### Calling Page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css.aspx">
```

#### Notes

- This doesn't include the necessary scaffolding for e.g. the `@Page` directive or `Page_Load` event
- This generalizes the query to work for multiple backgrounds, so you don't have a query for each element
- This assumes there is only one background per element type (e.g. `body`)
- This would also support a `placement` using CSS class names (e.g., `.header`)

Hope this helps!